# How to calculate number of days from a string like '1y2m3d', '2m3d', '1y3d', '1y' or simply '3d'

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, days

I want to create a filtering system in JavaScript. I have a string that contains a number of years, months, and days. I would like to transform this string to number of days format. So:

```
1y1m2d = 1*365+1*30+2
1y2d = 1*365+2
```

and so on. I have tried to create a regex for that:

```
/(\d+y)?(\d+m)?(\d+d)?/
```

However, the problem with this solution is that I am not able to know whether a group is for years, months, etc.

The second solution I tried was to use `.replace` and then pass it through `math.eval()` but this did not work for me. I am not sure why.

```
let result = stringFormat.replace(/y|m|d/, function (x) {
  return x === 'y' ? '*365' : x === 'm' ? '*12' : '*30';
});
```

In this scenario, we can assume that the number of days in a month is a constant, for example 30 days.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
const stringFormat = '1y1m2d'; 
let result = stringFormat.replace(/[ymd]/g, function (x, index, source) {
  return (x === 'y' ? '*365' : x === 'm' ? '*30' : '')+(index !== source.length-1 ? '+' : '');
});
console.log(result) // => 1*365+1*30+2
```

Notes:

- `/[ymd]/g` matches all occurrences of `y` or `m` or `d` in the string
- There are three arguments used in the callback function: `x` standing for the match value, `index` is the start match position, and `source` is the input string value
- If `y` is matched, the replacement is `*360` and `+` if the match is not at the end of string, if `m` is matched, the replacement is `*30` and `+`, and if `d` is matched, no multiplier is added.
- `(index !== source.length-1 ? '+' : '')` checks if the match is at the end of string, and adds `+` if necessary. It works like this because the match is always a single char.